# Excel - how to integrate multiple conditions to formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three conditions which all work perfectly fine.

I'd like to combine all of them into one formula but I'm faily new to EXCEL, tried a couple of things but no luck.

```
1. ensure the cell is not blank and there's no errors
=IF(ISBLANK(Database!xxx),"N/A",IFERROR(Database!xxx, "N/A"))

2. get the last value from a range of cells 
=INDEX(Database!T15:AE15, AGGREGATE(14, 6, COLUMN(A:O)/(Database!T15:AE15<>""), 1))
```

How do I combine the two above to ensure all the blanks and errors are caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with your aggregate function.  Just add the conditions from the IF statement to the denominator inside the aggregate function:

```
=INDEX(Database!T15:AE15,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(A1:O1)/((Database!T15:AE15<>"")*(Database!T15:AE15<>"N/A")*(NOT(ISERROR(Database!T15:AE15)))),1))
```

The `*` works like an `AND`

To deal with the problem when there are no valid inputs in the range then wrap it in an IFERROR:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Database!T15:AE15,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(A1:O1)/((Database!T15:AE15<>"")*(Database!T15:AE15<>"N/A")*(NOT(ISERROR(Database!T15:AE15)))),1)),"N/A")
```

Comment: This returns TRUE instead of the value from the cell

Comment: My bad. I got a little carried away with copy paste. See edit.

Comment: Now it's correctly pulling the value form the cell, but if the cell is blank then it returns a "#NUM!' error - really sorry to be a pain! so close

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(Database!F24),ISERROR(Database!F24)),"N/A",INDEX(Database!T15:AE15, AGGREGATE(14, 6, COLUMN(A:O)/(Database!T15:AE15<>""), 1)))
```

Comment: apologies, but the cell F24, wouldnt be hardcoded, so i'll be using the last call with a valid value from this range T15:AE15. How can I handle this.

Comment: I'm slightly confused - F24 isn't within the `T15:AE15` range

Comment: basically, I'm pulling the last cell from the range T15:AE15, whatever cell that maybe, I want to ensure its not blank, if true then return "N/A"